# Error java.lang.IllegalStateException:other must not be null

Tags: android, android-view

I am new in Android development and I provided my code snippet.
I'm wondering why is it saying `other must not be null`

```
other = findViewById(R.id.otherId)
```

My Activity:

```
class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var topAnimation:Animation
    lateinit var bottomAnimation:Animation
    lateinit var logoImage:ImageView
    lateinit var bangerText:TextView
   


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)

        topAnimation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.top_animation)
        bottomAnimation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.bottom_animation)


        logoImage=findViewById(R.id.logoImage)
        bangerText=findViewById(R.id.bangerTextView)
        val other=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView5)
        logoImage.animation=topAnimation
        bangerText.animation=bottomAnimation
            other.animation=bottomAnimation
        

    }
}
```

Comment: These kinds of XML errors usually happen when your are referencing the wrong id inside your activity/fragment that has a different XML file as a layout.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether layout/activity_splash_screen.xml actually has id/textView5?

If that id is not specified in that layout, findViewById might return null

Comment: yes it has  
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />